# webpack bundling - calling external Javascript from Typescript code

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a third-party Javascript library, which is not pure Typescript library.
To be more specific it's - https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512
There is no typing declaration for it, but I would like to avoid it anyway, since it's fairly simple library and I need to call just a couple of functions from there.

What I'm doing is:

```
// declaration    
import 'js-sha512'
declare function sha512(value: string): string;

// usage
var encryptedValue = sha512(this.internalValue);
```

The outcome is:

1. It works perfectly well with simple Typescript transpilation and including *sha512.js* file directly into the page.
2. When I'm building bundles with webpack - it builds successfully, which means that during build it finds all references.
3. After inspecting built bundles I see that sha512.js is included, which means  that "*import 'js-sha512'*" also doing it job correctly.
4. However after loading the page where it's used - it throws an error saying: '*sha512 is not defined*'.

Looks like this library is just not exposed/not accessible globally. If it's the case - how it could be solved? Or what else might be wrong?

Comment: You've linked the wrong library in your question - I think you mean https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for fixing me! :) Anyway - mentioned library is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation page probably is the source to possible solution:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html (for webpack1) or https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming (for webpack2).

In my particular case, having just a small Javascript library - [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader) worked quite well (because it's - "*just like you would add the code into a script tag*"):

```
require("script-loader!../node_modules/js-sha512/build/sha512.min.js");
```

However I understand it's not the best option. I tried briefly other things mentioned (like imports-loader, or ProvidePlugin, which works for jQuery's *$* shorthand), but it didn't work straight away - maybe because something else was missing, or maybe because library itself. So for now I will leave this answer.